# Can we test Grafana graphs using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, graph, automation, grafana, influxdb

We are automating a NMS Application (Network Management System) using Selenium. There are some monitoring graphs which are made using Grafana and InfluxDB. Is it possible to test those graphs using Selenium?

Comment: Can you share HTML in text format to get better reach on this question ?